# Unable to extract ZIP file created with Python using zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED compression method

Tags: java, python, zip

I have two programs (one in Java and one in Python) that ZIP a folder, upload it to a WebServer and trigger a UNZIP method on them.

The Java version of the program works without issues and the file is extracted on the server without problems.

Here I'm using the ArchiveStreamFactory class i.e. `new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveOutputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.ZIP, this.currentOutputStream);`

The Python version only works if I use `zipfile.ZIP_STORED` method (which does not compress the file). If I use the `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` method I get internal server error.

I don't have access to the server so for this I can only rely on what I'm able to figure out on my side.

The Java program does seem to use the ZIP_DEFLATED method also as the archive is compressed (smaller) and not just stored.

I've also run `zipinfo` on the both archives (the one created with Java and the one with Python with DEFLATE - which doesn't work) too see what's different.

Here's the output:

```
# Java
-rw----     2.0 fat    14398 bl defN  4-Jun-15 13:55 somefile.txt

# Python
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      183 b- defN 28-Jun-15 21:39 someotherfile.txt
```

Both seem to be compressed with DEFLATE (defN) method so why does the archive generated by Java works while the one generated by Python doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried  uncompressing the archives with a standard tool to compare their contents? It would help to show the actual code that does the compression in both programs. Also, learn to test components of your code in isolation, and create SSCCEs. You shouldn't have to worry about web servers in order to figure out if the compression is working properly.

Comment: Yes, with standard tool (the OSX unarchiver) works. So it must be something on their side (they run Java also) but as long the the archive made with Java works I guess it's just something that I haven't figured out yet in how Java compresses the files vs how Python does.

Comment: There is a huge diffrence in file size. 183 bytes vs 15000 bytes. Are you sure you are compressing the same thing in both?

Comment: It's different files (see the names). Ignore the size, I pasted that as I thought the other info is relevant (compression type, file system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging and trial and error looks like I found the issue in case anyone else is interested or will have the same problem.

I was also adding the folder to the zip and looks like it didn't liked the folders being compressed with ZIP_DEFLATED. What I did was to manually set the compression to ZIP_STORED for folders and to ZIP_DEFLATED for files and after this it worked. Interesting how Java knew to do this automatically behind the scenes, or at least I guess it does as the Java version is kind of the same (iterate over folders/files and add them to the ZIP) except I just use the default values (so I never explicitly set the compression type for anything).

So basically my code (the version that didn't worked) was something like this:

```
for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(absolute_folder_path, compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED):
    ...
    # Add folder to ZIP
    f_zip.write(absolute_dir_path, arcname=relative_dir_path)

    for file_name in file_names:
        ...
        # Add file to ZIP
        f_zip.write(absolute_file_path, arcname=relative_file_path)
```

and the fix was this one:

```
for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(absolute_folder_path):
    ...
    # Add folder to ZIP
    f_zip.write(absolute_dir_path, arcname=relative_dir_path, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_STORED)

    for file_name in file_names:
        ...
        # Add file to ZIP
        f_zip.write(absolute_file_path, arcname=relative_file_path, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: Thanks! Had the same problem!